# How to add extjs object to html?

Tags: extjs

I have a simple example:

```
 function RenderTime(v) {
    var test = new Ext.Img({
        src: "lib/Image/Paddle.png",
        listeners: {
            el: {
                click: function() {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Message");
                }
            }
        }
    })
     return '<table width="100%"><tr><td width="90%">' + test + '</td></tr></table>'

 }
```

and column:

```
  {
                dataIndex: 'title',
                width: 500,
                sortable : false,
                renderer: RenderTitle
        },
```

How to correct add extjs object to html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to utilize the "renderTo" attribute for your component rather than trying to concatenate it into your html manually.

See: [ExtJS Ext.Img.renderTo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Img-cfg-renderTo)